# Integrate a Python model in C# console app

Tags: python, c#, .net, python.net

I'm a student and currently writing a telegram bot in c# and I've separately written a communication model in Python. But I have problems with integrating the model into the bot code.
The best option is Python.NET because my model use pandas, sklearn, nltk and I have tried setting the PythonEngine.PythonPath to the correct path of my Python installation and have also referenced the Python.NET library. However, I keep encountering errors like BadPythonDllException and MissingMethodException.

I have confirmed that I have Python 3.11.2 installed on my computer, and the Python.NET library version matches my Python version and path to the Python DLL (python3.dll) is correct.

```
using System;
using Python.Runtime;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        PythonEngine.PythonPath = @"C:/Users/Leo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311";
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
        PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();

        using (var py = Py.GIL())
        {
            dynamic neuralNetwork = Py.Import("python/neural_network");
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction to fix it, that would be great.

Comment: Why don't you want to call the code from python itself. Try using a library called CTypes from your python code to use C# code files

Comment: I don't know anything about that library, but this scenario seems way too complex. Calling the target language (Python, here), performing all the actions there and returning a simplistic variable (a native one like a boolean or an int) would be one thing. Expecting that library to having fully mapped the C#-Python equivalences of the complex types which are probably returned by that code seems way too optimistic. I suggest you to keep it simple. Or just do everything with Python, write the results to a file/DB and read them from C#.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message that comes with `BadPythonDllException`.